# Highlighting a slickgrid row when clicked

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Humor me here. It seems like other grids like ExtJs do this out of the box, but for the life of me I can't find any solution to having a grid remain highlighted after a user clicks it. My interim solution is just a quick css rule to highlight a row on mouseover.

Are there really no options to just set this? It seems like I'm going to have to go through a rowSelection model and set it up so that only one row can be selected at a time, is that right?

Answer (score 7):

Your negative tone aside, I see nothing wrong with using the provided Slick.RowSeletionModel and setting multiSelect in grid options to false.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this RowSelectionModel?  I've seen it mentioned but I can't even find an example of it!

Comment: I just realized that the author recently (or at least I hope or I was blind before) added an example with row selection.  Anyone hoping to do this (and it's definitely the best and easiest way), check out this example: [Row selection & reordering](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this ([JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/HmtHq/)) :

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Augment grid object with a method to highlight the currently active row
//
mygrid.highlightActiveRow = function () {
  var currentCell;
  var $canvas = $(this.getCanvasNode());

  currentCell = this.getActiveCell();

  $canvas.find(".slick-row").removeClass("active");
  if (currentCell) {
    $canvas.find(".slick-row[row=" + currentCell.row + "]").addClass("active");
  }
};

mygrid.onActiveCellChanged.subscribe(function () {
  this.highlightActiveRow();
});
```

This marks the current row with the class `active` which can be styled as required:

```
/* Currently selected row */    
#mygrid .slick-row.active
{    
  background: #ff0000;
}

/* Currently selected cell */
#mygrid .slick-cell.active
{
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

There may be better ways to do this but this worked for me.